# Is it possible to install pyaudio on a webfaction server without using sudo?

Tags: python, django, pyaudio, webfaction

I am trying to install `PyAudio` inside my `webfaction` server.

[image]

It gives me the following error. I got the same error while installing it locally but I read the solution and the `sudo` command solves it. The problem is `webfaction` does not allow the `sudo` command.

What I have tried is that I copied my `pyaudio` local installation from site-packages folder to my online production server.

If I do pip freeze it shows me that it is installed. I tried running my function which uses `PyAudio` but it gives me the error

```
" Could not find PyAudio.Check installation"
```

**EDIT 1:**

The following code is going to solve the problem of installing port audio and pyaudio on web faction:

```
export CPPFLAGS="-I$HOME/include $CPPFLAGS"
export LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/lib $LDFLAGS"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
mkdir src
cd src
wget http://www.portaudio.com/archives/pa_stable_v190600_20161030.tgz
git clone https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/git/pyaudio.git
tar -xf pa_stable_v190600_20161030.tgz 
cd portaudio
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
cd ../pyaudio/
python2.7 setup.py install --prefix=$HOME
```

You can change the version of python to the version you currently have. I had 2.7 so I changed to it.

**EDIT2:**
This installs pyaudio and port audio. The problem is that I am still getting an error,  `"Pyaudio installation not found"`. Was there any error installing port audio or they have not been installed correctly?

**EDIT3:**

I figured out something that if you open the django shell inside and type import pyaudio. You will get the following error.

```
 Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/home/ammarkhan123/lib/python2.7/pyaudio.py", line 116, in <module>
 import _portaudio as pa
 ImportError: No module named _portaudio
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install python-dev package. And then install pyaudio. :D

Comment: python-dev is python-devel

Comment: Tried installing with yum but gives me an error. Need to be root to perform this action

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing portaudio. Since Webfaction is shared hosting, you can't install it system-wide. I'd suggest two remedies:

1) Open a ticket with Webfaction support and see if they will install the portaudio devel headers. I doubt this will work, but they've surprised me before.

2) Compile portaudio from source in your home directory, and then add the appropriate environment variables to your `.bash_profile`. I usually create `~/opt` as a place for all of my custom compiled libraries.

Instructions I wrote to do this for openssl are here: https://github.com/will-in-wi/letsencrypt-webfaction/wiki/Install-custom-OpenSSL-and-Ruby-on-CentOS-5-host

Instructions to custom compile MySQL are here: https://community.webfaction.com/questions/3838/compiling-a-private-mysql-installation-in-your-home-directory

Comment: I got it installed but the problem is that it still throws an error saying "Could not find PyAudio" Check installation

Comment: You still need to install pyaudio with PIP, probably in a virtual env. You will probably need some kind of environment variable or argument to define the location where portaudio is installed.

Comment: I have done that and there is this other command which is pip install --user pyaudio and it says successfully installed but still same error.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Have a look at the latest edit